# Cutting a convex body into two congruent pieces

Tags: convex-geometry, convexity

This question is related to [How to make a sandwich from just one piece of bread?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262919), asked on Feb 23 '17 by erz, and it goes as follows:

> **Question.** If a convex closed and bounded region $C$ in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be cut along some straight line into two congruent
>   pieces, must $C$ have either axial or central symmetry?

To be specific about what $cutting$ means, a $piece$ consists of the closure of the set of all points of $C$ that lie on the same side of the cutting line. Obviously, if $C$ has either axial or central symmetry, then it can be cut so.

The question can be phrased generally in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where we would cut a convex body along a hyperplane and consider $n$ kinds of symmetry, for example central, axial, and mirror in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I believe the answer is $yes$. Is it perhaps known already?

In retrospect (see Wlod AA's very nice answer): my intuition was way off.

Comment: It might be more revealing to consider two congruent  convex bodies glued together on a common shaped face.  The merged body may not seem as symmetric if an appropriate twist is given before gluing.  Gerhard "Even If One Maintains Convexity" Paseman, 2018.06.18.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, Yeah, there may be a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^3$ already.

Comment: If I am right then there are counter-examples in all dimensions $\ n>1$ (similar to the one in dimension $2$; it'd take more writing though).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a counter-example (in the complex plane $\mathbb C=\mathbb R^2.)\ $ Let

$$\ P\ :=
\ \{ (x\ y)\in\mathbb C : 0\le x\le 1\quad\&\quad 0\le y\le 1-x^2\} $$

Then,

$$ C\,\ :=\,\ P\,\cup\, i\!\cdot\! P $$

The imaginary line is the requested cut.

Comment: Do pay attention to the difference between $\ \mathbb C\ $ and $\ C.\ $ Sorry for this notational near-confusion.

Comment: Włodek, dziękuję ("thank you" for those who have never read Falski).

Comment: *Elementary, my dear Watson.*

Comment: Pure psychology! (Yes, *Elementary* and *Falski* go together well).

Comment: There is even a pentagonal counter-example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that your idea produces.

Comment: One can see automatically a bunch of similar examples but pentagonal? I'd like to see it! Oh, of course, now I see it too. :) Thank you, Włodek, for telling me. Indeed, 5-gon sounds strange at first.